# How to delete graphics from PCB board view in Eagle?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication

I am making my first PCB, and I have a numpad and a 16x2 LCD in the schematic. When I go to make the board, it also brings in the graphics along with the pins, but I will not be soldering them directly to the PCB and I don't want the graphics showing up on the PCB. I will likely solder pin headers, before connecting the devices via jumper wires.

Should I replace these parts with pin headers in the schematic? Or is there a way I can disable the graphics?

[image: screenshot of PCB view in Eagle]

Comment: You may be able to change the footprint associated with the display and keypad schematic symbols.  I don't know Eagle, but other CAD programs I've used allow you to select different footprints to go with a schematic symbol.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to copy the device into your own library and modify its package there. If you continue using Eagle sooner or later you'd have to make your own devices. This seems to be a good time to begin.

And while you at it I'd recommend adding pin names to the display package, it might be helpful later for connecting jumper wires.